# How many elements will be in the array?

Tags: c++

```
char a [] = "EFG\r\n" ;
```

How many elements will be in the array created by the declaration above?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

6 characters: `E` `F` `G` `\r` `\n` `\0`

You can see this for yourself by running:

```
char a [] = "EFG\r\n" ;
printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
// 6
```

The following code shows you the value for each byte:

```
char a [] = "EFG\r\n" ;
int length = sizeof(a), i;
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    printf("0x%02x ", a[i]);
}
// 0x45 0x46 0x47 0x0d 0x0a 0x00
```

Comment: D'oh, I spent too long in my little TMP world. :)

Comment: N.B: You don't need parentheses with sizeof.

Answer (score 48):

6, with proof by [Ideone](http://ideone.com/8X5ow) (look at the errors).

---

**Edit:** Actually, the example looked like this at first:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, int N>
int length_of(T (&arr)[N]){
  return N;
}

int main(){
  char a [] = "EFG\r\n" ;
  std::cout << length_of(a) << std::endl;
}
```

But I wanted to keep it short and avoid includes. :)

Comment: haha wow that's an amazing way to show the answer... wish could double-upvote